How to add no-follow code to WooCommerce product attribute archives?
So I have a WooCommerce store on Wordpress. I have product attributes set up, so that items can be classed, e.g. organic, gluten-free, and each of these attributes has a 'yes' and a 'no' page. When you click on one of these, you can see all products with that attribute.
While this is useful for customers, it causes massive bloat from an SEO perspective in terms of total pages indexed. So I'm looking to add no-follow to these pages.
Something like this should do it:

However, I see no way to actually add code to attribute pages on Wordpress. I tried the page edit options in the admin toolbar above the page, but these seem to be for editing the entire site. Editing products is easier as there is a UX editor available, but not with attributes.
Would anyone have an idea of how to do this?

There are some approaches you can use to achieve what you want.
Using Robots.txt
You can add specific rules to your robots.txt file to prevent search engines from indexing certain attribute URLs.
For example:
User-agent: *
Disallow: /product-attribute/pa_organic/
Disallow: /product-attribute/pa_glutenfree/

This will block search engines from indexing the specified attribute pages. You might need to change these depending on your actual attributes.

Adding Custom Code
For more granular control, you can add custom code to the functions.php file, in your child theme, to add nofollow meta tags to specific product attributes. Here’s a basic example:
add_action('wp_head', 'noindex_specific_attributes');
function noindex_specific_attributes() {
    if (is_tax('pa_organic') || is_tax('pa_glutenfree')) {
        echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">';
    }
}


add_action('wp_head', 'noindex_specific_attributes'); This hooks
your custom function into the wp_head action, which runs in the
<head> section of your site.
is_tax('pa_organic') || is_tax('pa_glutenfree') This checks if the
current page is a taxonomy archive page for either the pa_organic
or pa_glutenfree attributes. You might need to change these
depending on your actual attributes.
echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">'; This
outputs the noindex, nofollow meta tag, instructing search
engines not to index these pages or follow links on them.


Plugins
There are also plugins available that can help manage the visibility of product attributes. For instance the Yoast SEO plugin.

Thanks for answering. I've already added the disallows to robots.txt but Google still seems to be indexing the pages.
Here's what I have:
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /gluten-free/no/
Disallow: /irish/yes/
Disallow: /irish/no/
Disallow: /vegan/yes/
Disallow: /vegan/no/
Disallow: /irish/yes/
Disallow: /irish/no/
Disallow: /organic/yes/
Disallow: /organic/no/
(We decided to allow the gluten-free/yes option)

Changes to the robots.txt file might take some time to be reflected in Google’s index. It can take up to 24 hours for Google to recrawl and update its cached version of your robots.txt file. However, you can request a recrawl directly in the Google Search Console by using the Robots Testing Tool
Also ensure your sitemap does not include URLs you want to disallow. If these URLs are in your sitemap, Google might still try to index them.
